# Android's ConstraintLayout - anchor a view to 2 guidelines

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), i'm trying to anchor a view to 2 `guidelines`, as you can see in the blueprint in the attached screenshot.

[image]

How ever, the view is placed at the top-left corner of the screen, instead of being constrained by the two guidelines.
Any idea why this hapens?

Thanks!

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:background="#FAFA00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="576dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="422dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="178dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You can report this bug here: http://tools.android.com/feedback

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug related to guidelines that was fixed in beta4 -- try updating, it should fix your problem.